# Flutter: NoSuchMethodError only on Android

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to fix this rather annoying bug. My app has a sliverList with data (fetched from a json web resource). Up until a few days ago I was able to run it in both, ios and android.

**Now I get the following error message:**

```
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null. 
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length
```

**The full error message is at the end.**

when navigating to line 49 of the file in question according to the error message I have the following code:

```
new ZoopediaPage(widget.res),
```

after passing the widget.res (which was already passed from the splash screen).

the `.length` itself is used here:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  List response = widget.res;
  int rnd = randomGen(0, widget.res.length);
```

Within the ZoopediaPage I have the following code:

```
class ZoopediaPage extends StatefulWidget {
  List res;
  ZoopediaPage(this.res);
  //const ZoopediaPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ZoopediaPageState createState() => _ZoopediaPageState();
}
```

When using `print(widget.res)` I have the result in the console.

My guess is, that for some reason my android device has some issues with loading the data but I have no clue why it has the issue all the sudden and why only on android?

```
Future fetchData() async {
  http.Response response;
  response =
      await http.get('https://apps.lechner.io/zoopedia/zoopedia_animals.json');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    setState(() {
      res = json.decode(response.body);
      print('(DEBUG) Data Loaded successfully');
    });
  }
}
```

on android the internet permission is set too.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**with the full error message here:**

```
Performing hot reload...                                               ⣻
Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called
on null.
        
Reloaded 1 of 619 libraries in 214ms.

Performing hot reload...                                               ⣻
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building ZoopediaPage(dirty, state:
_ZoopediaPageState#8c021):
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length

The relevant error-causing widget was:
ZoopediaPage
file:///Users/lechnerio/dev/flutter/zoopedia/app/lib/ZoopediaApp.dart:49:15

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _ZoopediaPageState.build (package:zoopedia/pages/zoopedia.dart:38:39)
#2      StatefulElement.build
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4742:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4625:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4797:11)
#5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#6      StatefulElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4829:5)
#7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#8      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6111:14)
#9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#10     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6111:14)
#11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#12     ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#13     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#14     StatelessElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4706:5)
#15     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#16     ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#17     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#18     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4973:5)
#19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#20     ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#21     StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4797:11)
#22     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#23     StatefulElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4829:5)
#24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#25     ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#26     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#27     StatelessElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4706:5)
#28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#29     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1229:37)
#30     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild.processElement
(package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1145:35)
#31     Iterable.forEach (dart:core/iterable.dart:283:30)
#32     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1187:24)
#33     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1124:7)
#34     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#35     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6111:14)
#36     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#37     ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#38     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#39     StatelessElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4706:5)
#40     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#41     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5633:32)
#42     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6235:17)
#43     _ViewportElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/viewport.dart:228:11)
#44     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#45     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6111:14)
#46     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#47     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6111:14)
#48     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#49     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6111:14)
#50     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#51     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6111:14)
#52     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#53     ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#54     StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4797:11)
#55     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#56     StatefulElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4829:5)
#57     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#58     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6111:14)
#59     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#60     ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#61     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#62     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4973:5)
#63     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#64     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6111:14)
#65     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#66     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6111:14)
#67     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#68     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6111:14)
#69     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#70     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6111:14)
#71     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#72     ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#73     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#74     StatelessElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4706:5)
#75     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#76     ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#77     StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4797:11)
#78     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#79     StatefulElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4829:5)
#80     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#81     ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#82     StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4797:11)
#83     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#84     StatefulElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4829:5)
#85     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#86     ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#87     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#88     StatelessElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4706:5)
#89     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#90     ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#91     StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4797:11)
#92     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#93     StatefulElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4829:5)
#94     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#95     ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#96     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#97     StatelessElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4706:5)
#98     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#99     ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#100    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#101    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4973:5)
#102    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#103    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#104    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#105    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4973:5)
#106    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#107    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5633:32)
#108    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6235:17)
#109    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#110    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#111    StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4797:11)
#112    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#113    StatefulElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4829:5)
#114    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#115    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#116    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#117    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4973:5)
#118    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#119    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#120    StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4797:11)
#121    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#122    StatefulElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4829:5)
#123    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#124    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6111:14)
#125    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#126    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#127    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#128    StatelessElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4706:5)
#129    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#130    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6111:14)
#131    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#132    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#133    StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4797:11)
#134    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#135    StatefulElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4829:5)
#136    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#137    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#138    StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4797:11)
#139    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#140    StatefulElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4829:5)
#141    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#142    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#143    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#144    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4973:5)
#145    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#146    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#147    StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4797:11)
#148    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#149    StatefulElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4829:5)
#150    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#151    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4650:16)
#152    StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4797:11)
#153    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4319:5)
#154    BuildOwner.buildScope
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2694:33)
#155    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
(package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:869:21)
#156    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
(package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:319:5)
#157    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#158    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
#159    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:865:7)
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and
dart:async-patch)

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
════════════════════
```

Comment: You called API on the first page and send this data to second page right?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede yes. basically the first page is a splashscreen and fetching the data. the data is then passed to the main page itself and part of the data gets passed further to a detail page

Comment: Okay and what is `randomGen`? can you add this?

Comment: function looks like this: https://pastebin.com/s79pNdea and is just there to select a random image from all the data

Comment: I guess the issue is that the widget (`widget.res`) is empty, but I'm struggling to understand why it's only empty on android

Comment: Im not sure but i think when you navigate this code is wrong so you are facing this issue

Comment: `widget.res` is `null`. Did you pass `res` to the `widget` in which you use it?

Comment: widget.res is only null on android. on the ios emulator the api url can be fetched and returns data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not caused by any code.

For some reason the android emulator had no internet and I was unable to connect to it.

Setting the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` did not help.

I created a new android device and it worked just out of the box.